# jQuery Mobile application when iframe inserted Back button does not function

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, video, iframe

When I put an iframe for a video that plays within my application the Back button on the jQuery UI Header does not function anymore.

When I take the iframe out of the code it functions correctly again. Wondering if anyone knows the fix here is the code for the page with the iframe on.

```
<div data-role="page" id="about" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Back" >

<div data-role="header" >
    <h1>About</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">

    <div id ="aboutsection">
        <div id="about-logo"><img src="images/small-logo.png" /></div>

        <div id="video-thumb">
        <a href="#popupVideo" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window"><img src="images/video-thumb.png"/></a>        
        <div data-role="popup" id="popupVideo" data-tolerance="15,15" class="ui-content">
                <iframe src="
                http://player.vimeo.com/video/54553882?portrait=0" seamless></iframe>
            </div>
        </div><!--/video-thumb-->
        <p>&#169; Be Active North-East</p>
    </div><!--/aboutsection-->
</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <h4>Be Active North East </h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->
```

Answer (score 1):

I similar problems, and got pretty good result with this js;

```
function goBack(){
    var url = $.mobile.urlHistory.getPrev().url;
    if (url === null || url == "") url = $.mobile.firstPage.attr("data-url");
    $.mobile.changePage(url, "slide", true, true, true);
}
```

And this back button

```
<a href="" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="back" onclick="goBack()">Back</a>
```